# How to solve $f\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve $f\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$? (where $f(x,t)$ is assumed to be in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R})$)

I can find a particular solution which is $f=\frac{x}{t}$. Is this the only solution? If not how can I find all the other solution?

Comment: Anyway, the [Method of Characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) seems promising. You should try it out!

Comment: Using the Method of Characteristics, you get solutions of the form
$$
f(x,t) = \dfrac{x - x_{0}}{t - t_{0}},
$$
where $ (x_{0},t_{0}) \in \mathbb{R} \times (- \infty,0] $ (if you require that $ f \in {C^{\infty}}(\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)) $).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $f(x,t)$ satisfies the given condition, then $f(x-a,t-b)$ also satisfies the given condition.

Along the curve $x(t)$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\tag{1}
$$
the given condition implies that $f$ will remain constant on curves where
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=f\tag{2}
$$
Suppose $f(x_0,t_0)=a$. Then $f(x,t)=a$ on the line where $\frac{x-x_0}{t-t_0}=a$.

Suppose we know that $f(x,0)=\phi(x)$, then
$$
f(x+\phi(x)t,t)=\phi(x)\tag{3}
$$

---

If we use $\phi(x)=x$ in $(3)$, we get
$$
f(x+xt,t)=x\implies f(x,t)=\frac x{t+1}\tag{4}
$$
which is a translate of your function $f(x,t)=\frac xt$.

---

If we use $\phi(x)=x^2$ in $(3)$, we get
$$
f(x+x^2t,t)=x^2\implies f(x,t)=\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4xt}}{2t}\right)^2\tag{5}
$$
Thus, we can generate different functions $f$ given different functions $\phi$.

---

O.L. mentions that the equation
$$
f\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0\tag{6}
$$
is called the [Inviscid Burgers' Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation).

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood edit.  It might be good to clarify that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is a slope, since the inexperienced among us may get confused trying to interpret it as an ordinary derivative in context.

Comment: @Slade: At the expense of a very slight bit of generality, I have gotten rid of the auxiliary variable $s$. I hope it gets rid of the confusion.

Comment: @robjohn +1. It might be helpful to mention that this is called the inviscid Burgers equation.

Comment: @O.L.: Thanks! I hadn't known that before.